# Long definition with braces

Tags: line-breaking, braces

I know, maybe this topic is duplicate but I didn't find the correct answer.

```
\begin{align*}
\Theta(g(n)) = \left{f(n)|\>\>  \text{existují}\>\>   c_1 >0, c_2 > 0 \>\>  \text{a}\>\>  n_0\in  \>\>\textbf{N}\>\>  
 \text{tak,} \right.\\ \left. \text{ že pro každé}\>\>  n \geq n_0 \>\>  \text{je}\>\> 0\leq c_1 g(n)\leq f(n) \leq c_2g(n) \right}

\end{align*}
```

I have in the first row one brace and in the second row is another brace. Latex still doesn't want to do it correctly. Can you help me ?

Comment: Instead of `\left{` and `\right}` you probably have `\left\{` and `\right\}` in your real file I guess? Matching parentheses of any sort on different lines are much easier achieved with `\bigl` and `\bigr` (and friends) instead of `\left` and `\right`...

Comment: All `\big...` variants are for example explained in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode

Comment: please notice the subtle difference in `\bigl{` (wrong) vs `\bigl\{` (right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Theta(g(n))=\bigl\{f(n)|\>\> \text{existují}\>\> c_1 >0, c_2 > 0 \>\> \text{a}\>\> n_0\in \>\>\text{\textbf{N}tak,} 
\\ 
\text{že pro každé}\>\> n \geq n_0 \>\>  \text{je}\>\> 0\leq c_1 g(n)\leq f(n) \leq c_2g(n) \bigr\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

When you use `\bigl\{` on the left, you need `\bigr\{` on the right.

Comment: Wouldn't `\text{ existují }` make more sense than `\>\> \text{existují}\>\>` (similar in the other cases)?

Comment: Yes, but i want to be cool :D

Comment: The space between "\in" and "**N**tak" on the first line seems much too large.

Comment: i think you mean `\bigr\}` instead of the opening brace.

Answer (score 1):

*Please* don't abuse math spacing directives. Instead, use $...$ formulas inside `\text{...}` wrappers on both lines of the formula. That way, not a single `\>` spacing directive is needed -- and the code becomes a lot more legible to boot.

Also, don't use `|` (vertical bar) as the symbol to indicate a conditioning step; instead, use `\mid` or `\bigm|` if you want the larger version.

And, since the `\left` and `\right` prefixes don't succeed in enlarging the curly braces (since the material they enclose isn't tall), you should use `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Theta\bigl(g(n)\bigr) = \bigl\{ f(n) \bigm|{} 
&\text{existují $c_1 >0, c_2 > 0 $ a $n_0\in\mathbf{N}\text{tak}$,} \\ 
&\text{že pro každé $n \geq n_0$ je $0\leq c_1 g(n)\leq f(n) \leq c_2g(n)$} \bigr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\Theta(g(n)) = \{ f(n)\mid \text{existují } c_1 >0, c_2 > 0 \text{ a } n_0\in \numberset{N} \text{ tak,} \\
&\qquad\text{že pro každé } n \geq n_0 \text{ je } 0\leq c_1 g(n)\leq f(n) \leq c_2g(n) \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\Theta(g(n)) = \{ &f(n)\mid \text{existují } c_1 >0, c_2 > 0 \text{ a } n_0\in \numberset{N} \text{ tak,} \\
                  &\text{že pro každé } n \geq n_0 \text{ je } 0\leq c_1 g(n)\leq f(n) \leq c_2g(n) \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{multline*}
\Theta(g(n)) = \{ f(n)\mid \text{existují } c_1 >0, c_2 > 0 \text{ a } n_0\in \numberset{N} \text{ tak,} \\
   \text{že pro každé } n \geq n_0 \text{ je } 0\leq c_1 g(n)\leq f(n) \leq c_2g(n) \}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that LaTeX prefers `\;` to `\>` (that also works, though); however, using `\;\;` is *always* wrong. Check how I got the spacing.

You seem to believe that `\left{` is correct syntax: it isn't. It should be `\left\{` (with the corresponding `\right\}`) but in this case it does nothing useful.

Also `\textbf{N}` should be `\mathbf{N}` or, better, like I did adding in the preamble

```
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

and using `\numberset{N}`. Though this might seem longer to type, it adds semantics; when your advisor or the copy editor will tell you “Dear Micky, you *must* use `\mathbb` for number set names”, you'll be glad to comply by just changing *one* line in your document.